# Can't mount detected hard drive

Tags: linux, debian, mount, hard-disk

I have a pretty big issue with my hard drive. I wasn't able to read it anymore with my Windows so I deciced to count on my linux partition to save my life.
I'm able to see my hard drive with `lsblk` but impossible to mount with `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb`
[Here is my case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14uc3.png)

What can I do ? I am totally lost, for real.

Thanks for your attention and help

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is it formatted NTFS?

Comment: Are there any messages in `dmesg` regarding `sdc`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses
@jc__ Actually, I am not getting any error of message to guide me. Is there any log files for those kind of bugs ?

Comment: @ErikF Here is what I have :
` [  228.170704] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 147047294
[  228.170706] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 147045246, async page read`

I don't know how to interpret it

Comment: IO errors. Not looking good, you may need to look into recovery options now to try and save _some_ of the data.

Comment: Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550840/buffer-i-o-errors) at the answer for some guidance.

Comment: Thanks @jc__, I'll follow that path and try to fix it. I'll be back then !